# how to compile ffmpeg with librtmp in macos?

Tags: macos, rtmp, homebrew

I've tried installing ffmpeg in mac lion through homebrew like this:

```
brew install --use-clang ffmpeg --with-tools --with-ffplay --enable-librtmp
```

but the compile flags ended up as

```
configuration: --disable-debug --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/0.6.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --disable-indev=jack --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libfaad
```

What's the correct way to install ffmpeg with librtmp? I also want to run libavfilters like blackdetect.

Doing a direct install always failed with RTMP_Socket() missing so I was hoping for a homebrew solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally able to compile! Think the key might have been running

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

just before configure but not sure since i was getting different errors according to the flags. The [script](https://gist.github.com/2863964) I ended up running (modified from other sources) is at github: https://gist.github.com/2863964

Comment: i have the same issue as you , do i just have to run the sh to compile the ffmpeg?

Answer (score 6):

You can include librtmp in the build by adding the `--with-rtmpdump` flag (after installing RTMPDump). These are the commands I used:

```
brew install rtmpdump
brew install ffmpeg --with-x265 --with-rtmpdump
```

Now I have rtmp, rtmpe, rtmps, rtmpt and rtmpte as available protocols! :)